# Large form with scrollbar and textboxs with multiline. How to prevent mouse wheel stops when touch one textbox?

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in a custom control:

```
Class CustomControl1
Inherits TextBox
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    Select Case m.Msg
        ' WM_MOUSEWHEEL
        Case &H20A, &H20E
            ' WM_MOUSEHWHEEL
            If Me.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None AndAlso Me.Parent IsNot Nothing Then
                m.HWnd = Me.Parent.Handle

            End If
            ' forward this to your parent
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
            Exit Select
        Case Else

            MyBase.WndProc(m)
            Exit Select
    End Select
End Sub
End Class
```

It is assumed that this is a solution I found online, but does not work. Can someone tell me, if it's correct or if there is another way?

Comment: That cannot work, you'll have to "forward" with SendMessage().

Comment: How can I do it? You could put a small example ?
thx

Comment: Use google, query "c# wm_mousewheel sendmessage".

Comment: I did not find anything useful on sendmessage to VB.net